# why ng-change give "undefined" in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could you please tell me why `ng-change` give "undefined" in angularjs ?

```
$scope.onChangedCityDropDown= function(i){
    console.log(i)
}
<select class="form-control" ng-model="a"
        ng-options="item.city as item.city for item in vals" 
        ng-change="onChangedCityDropDown(item)">
    <option value="" disabled>choose an option</option>
</select>
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/HLLUcVnIl8ySg8baSMHv?p=preview

Comment: You need to pass `a` i.e. `onChangedCityDropDown(a)` and I think you need `ng-options="item.city as item for item in vals"`

Comment: use a instead of item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your ng-options as below this will give you the object you are expecting.

```
ng-options="item as item.city for item in vals"
ng-change="onChangedCityDropDown(a)"
```

in `ng-change` you have to pass your `ng-model`

here is the working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xYVIDAanoVWuT9ThFBes?p=preview)

Comment: let take $scope.state ='' initially .but when I change to "gurgoan" it city value is "gurgoan" and state is "haryana"

Comment: I will explain what I am trying to do ..I have one dropdown where city is display . and on change of city I want to show the state

Comment: sorry i am not getting your point. in your example both city is under one state

Comment: @Joy you can get the corresponsing state value from the code i have shared. get the state by i.state and then update or show where ever u want.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the ng-model value to the function,

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="a" ng-options="item.city as item.city for item in vals" ng-change="onChangedCityDropDown(a)">
    <option value="" disabled>choose an option</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I want "state" value from selected option or object I want corresponding state value

Comment: if I select "gurgaon" state should be "haryana"

Comment: this is not a correct answer I need if user select "gurgoan" or other option .I need it  corresponding state value

Answer (score 1):

`ng-options` doesn't work the same way as that of `ng-repeat` works. You won't get `item` value apart from `ng-options` attribute value. To make it work you should use `ng-model`(a) value inside `ng-change` callback function.

```
ng-change="onChangedCityDropDown(a)"
```

Also you want to set `state` based on city selection then change ng-options to below

```
ng-options="item.state as item.city for item in vals"
```

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uGogZb8T4NlFlwFPlDcI?p=preview)

Comment: I want selected object

Comment: I want corresponding state value

Comment: I want "state" value from selected option or object I want corresponding state value

Comment: if I select "gurgaon" state should be "haryana"

Comment: if I select "gurgaon" state should be "haryana"

Comment: this is not a correct answer I need if user select "gurgoan" or other option .I need it  corresponding state value

Comment: @Joy give me a moment

Comment: @Joy you have to tweak a `ng-options` expression a bit

Comment: you didn't my Question

Comment: I will explain what I am trying to do ..I have one dropdown where city is display . and on change of city I want to show the state

Comment: let take $scope.state ='' initially .but when I change to "gurgoan" it city value is "gurgoan" and state is "haryana"

Comment: @Joy can you please add the other dropdown in the plunker, I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

just change `onChangedCityDropDown(item)` to `onChangedCityDropDown(a)`

[see](https://plnkr.co/edit/aFR0RNgriKxgWzFrupP7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code for the city and the state reference selection and also please check [this plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/vUpcQeRkflE5PLawR4Dh?p=preview) of your given working example.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.vals = [{
    "city":"gurgaon",
    "state":"Haryana"
  }, {
    "city":"Manesar",
    "state":"Haryana"
  }, {
    "city":"Bangalore",
    "state":"Karnataka"
  }]; 

  $scope.onChangedCityDropDown= function(i){
    console.log(i)
  }

  $scope.onChangedStateDropDown= function(i){
    console.log(i)
  }
```

**Template:**

```
City
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-options="item.city as item.city for item in vals" ng-change="onChangedCityDropDown(city)">
    <option value="" disabled>Select City</option>
</select>
State
<select  class="form-control" ng-model="state" ng-options="item.state as item.state for item in vals | filter:{city:city}" ng-change="onChangedStateDropDown(state)">
    <option value="" disabled>Select State</option>
</select>
```